# Jhipster generated app, default AngularJS register form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jhipster

I created an app using JHipster and try to edit the `register.html'. The code where I need help is shows below:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" ng-show="vm.success" data translate="register.messages.success">
    <strong>Registration saved!</strong> Please check your email for confirmation.
</div>

<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="vm.error" data-translate="register.messages.error.fail">
    <strong>Registration failed!</strong> Please try again later.
</div>
```

I omitted the rest of the code as they are equal to these two, only with different messages and `ng-models` . & the `register.controller.js` :

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('MyApp')
    .controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);


RegisterController.$inject = ['$translate', '$timeout', 'Auth', 'LoginService'];

function RegisterController ($translate, $timeout, Auth, LoginService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.doNotMatch = null;
    vm.error = null;
    vm.errorUserExists = null;
    vm.login = LoginService.open;
    vm.register = register;
    vm.registerAccount = {};
    vm.success = null;

    $timeout(function (){angular.element('#login').focus();});

    function register () {
        if (vm.registerAccount.password !== vm.confirmPassword) {
            vm.doNotMatch = 'ERROR';
        } else {
            vm.registerAccount.langKey = $translate.use();
            vm.doNotMatch = null;
            vm.error = null;
            vm.errorUserExists = null;
            vm.errorEmailExists = null;

            Auth.createAccount(vm.registerAccount).then(function () {
                vm.success = 'OK';
            }).catch(function (response) {
                vm.success = null;
                if (response.status === 400 && response.data === 'login already in use') {
                    vm.errorUserExists = 'ERROR';
                } else if (response.status === 400 && response.data === 'e-mail address already in use') {
                    vm.errorEmailExists = 'ERROR';
                } else {
                    vm.error = 'ERROR';
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
})();
```

My question is by default the error handling messages must be hidden, and once the form is valuated, they should be shown based on the condition. But I cannot figure out how to make this work...
Below is the default `register.html` page: 
[image: Default register page]

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are looking for. It seems like you want to implement form validation. if that is the case use ng-messages. This links explains it nicely http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/05/how-to-use-ngmessages-in-angularjs.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will go through that. My main concern is that, the messages shown in picture must be hidden by default when the form is loaded, and once the form is evaluated, the related message should appear. but in this case ( and the default jhispter app) all of the messages are shown by default.

Comment: ng-messages will take care of it. It will show the message based on validations and only the ones which fail will be shown

Answer (score 1):

The generated register.html does not show those messages by default.  It looks like you are loading just the HTML file into the browser, but you need to run the app and load the index.html from there to run the Angular code.

Run `./mvnw` or `./gradlew` and access the frontend at http://localhost:8080
You can also run `gulp` which will serve your frontend at http://localhost:9000 with live-reloading when you make changes.  More info can be found in the [Using JHipster in development](http://jhipster.github.io/development/) documentation

The register page looks like the following image when ran correctly: [image]

Comment: Yes @Jon Ruddell.. the reason was the controller was not loaded and I changed a few things.. so I did a `git status`, found the mistakes and got it to work again..